# getOrCreate for java-rest-api neo4j fails

Tags: neo4j

I have a simple relationship test that I am trying to run to create a unique node using Rest API (java-rest-binding) https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding but unfortunately I am stuck on something, here are the details: (the non-unique node and relationship works perfectly fine, its with this that it doesn't, most likely I am doing something naive (pardon my lack on knowledge of neo4j).

```
final UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
        final HashMap<String, Object> uModelAttributes = new HashMap<String, Object>(0);
        uModelAttributes.put("name", "AnirudhVyas");
        userModel.setAttributes(uModelAttributes);
        final HashSet<Action> buyHistory = new HashSet<Action>();
        final Action buyAction = new Action();
        final ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
        final HashMap<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>(0);
        attributes.put("name", "mercedes benz ");
        attributes.put("make", "mercedes benz");
        attributes.put("model", "sls 550");
        attributes.put("year", "2014");
        productModel.setAttributes(attributes);
        buyAction.setProduct(productModel);
        buyHistory.add(buyAction);
        userModel.setBuyHistory(buyHistory);
        System.out.println("Before");
        new UserModelDAO().createCompleteTree(userModel);
        System.out.println("Completed >>>
```

if i use this on the dao:

```
final RestNode root = api.getOrCreateNode(api.index().forNodes("users", MapUtil.stringMap(IndexManager.PROVIDER, "lucene", "type", "fulltext")), "name", m
                    .getAttributes().get("name"), m.getAttributes());

api.getOrCreateNode(api.index().forNodes("products", MapUtil.stringMap(IndexManager.PROVIDER, "lucene", "type", "fulltext")), "name", buyAction.getProduct().getAttributes().get("name"), buyAction.getProduct().getAttributes()), RelationshipTypes.BOUGHT);
```

This basically Fails with:

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Error retrieving or creating node for key name and value AnirudhVyas with index users
        at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.getOrCreateNode(ExecutingRestAPI.java:448)
        at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade.getOrCreateNode(RestAPIFacade.java:223)
        at xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.graph.UserModelCreateTasteKeyNeo4JBatchCallback.recordBatch(UserModelCreateTasteKeyNeo4JBatchCallback.java:61)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do it, one of them is using Cypher:

```
MATCH a
WHERE a.name! = 'nameTofound'
CREATE UNIQUE a-[:Relationship]-c:LABEL
RETURN c
```

Use it inside a queryEngine.
It works like a charm, please look at the following link for more details:
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-create-unique.html

Java code is here:

```
protected static RestNode createOrGetExistingNode(String key, String valueFor, String Rel, String label){
    RestNode node = null;
    final QueryResult<Map<String, Object>> result = GraphRestService.queryEngine.query(String.format("MATCH node WHERE node.%s! ='%s' " +
            "CREATE UNIQUE node-[:%s]-c:%s RETURN c" , key, valueFor, Rel, label), MapUtil.map("reference", 0));
    for (Map<String, Object> column : result) {
        node = (RestNode) column.get("c");
    }
    return node;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by not using batch rest callback - When I simply use - getOrCreateXXX( ) for RestAPI it works like a charm - Need to investigate further as to why getOrCreate on BatchCallback#recordBatch( ) will behave differently.

Comment: The batch operations are just recording your calls and then replay them on the execution of your block, so any kind of reading is only delayed until the block is actually executed.

Comment: Care to give more details?